# Best library and implementation to handle my measurement data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have got a lot of measurement data to analyze in Python. Each dataset consists of a parameter set (scalars with numbers, dates and strings) and two curves.

The goal is to be able to filter (select based on criteria), group, cluster, analyze (e.g. mean of all curves and parameters in a group) and visualize datasets or groups of them.

I started to implement this with Pandas and created a Dataframe with a column for each parameter and the measurement ID as the index. Then I added a column for the curves, such that each field in that column contains the two curves as a dict of two numpy arrays.

Here is an example implementation (the real dataframe has thousands of datasets with tens of parameters columns)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

example_dataset_nr = 5
# Column titles
columns = ['DateTime', 'PositionX', 'Filter', 'Curves']

# Generate arbitrary parameter data to fill example Dataframe
dates = [pd.Timestamp(i*10000000) for i in range(example_dataset_nr)]
positions = np.random.rand(example_dataset_nr)
filters = ['green']*example_dataset_nr

# Generate curves, such that each field in the Dataframes "Curves"-column contains
# a dict with two curves, each as a array of points:
curves = [{'curve_voltage': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100,2)), 'curve_current': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100))} for i in range(example_dataset_nr)]

# Create Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([dates, positions, filters, curves]).T, columns=columns)
df['PositionX'] = df['PositionX'].astype(np.float)
df.index.rename('MeasurementID', inplace=True)
print(df.to_string())
```

Now, if I analyze the data with operations like "df.mean()", Pandas does of course not know how to handle the curves. I want pandas to operate on the curves like it does on the other numeric fields. As an example, lets say df.mean(), Pandas should calculate the mean of all curves, and not only the parameters in the Dataframe.

```
# Get the mean of all numeric types. Want to get the mean curves of all 'curve_voltage' and 'curve_current', too.
df.mean()
```

I wonder, which is the best way to implement such behaviour in Python?

Here are some suggestions:

1. Pandas: Using separate dataframes or series for the curves and connect them to a pure "parameter dataframe" through foreign keys. But then is the question how do I automatically forward all methods from the "parameter dataframe" to the "curves dataframe" without reemplementing them?
2. Pandas: Subclass Dataframe. Or any other way of extending Pandas. I read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html, but I am not sure which is the right way to go here. Again the same question of forwarding methods in a sensefull way.
3. Xarray: I have never used it, but is Xarray a better tool for my needs, then pandas?
4. Database: Is a database better suited, with something like SQL?
5. Are there other viable options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this would be a good use case for xarray, since it naturally supports combining tabular (1-dimensional) data with higher-dimensional data (your curves).

With xarray, you can build your dataset like this:

```py
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.Dataset(
    {
        'DateTime': (['MeasurementID'], dates),
        'PositionX': (['MeasurementID'], positions),
        'Filter': (['MeasurementID'], filters),
        'curve_voltage': (['MeasurementID', 'curve_x', 'curve_y'], [row['curve_voltage'] for row in curves]),
        'curve_current': (['MeasurementID', 'curve_x'], [row['curve_current'] for row in curves]),
    },
    coords={
        'MeasurementID': np.arange(len(dates)),
        'curve_x': np.arange(100),
        'curve_y': np.arange(2)
    }
)
```

And work with it like this:

```
>>> ds
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:        (MeasurementID: 5, curve_x: 100, curve_y: 2)
Coordinates:
  * MeasurementID  (MeasurementID) int64 0 1 2 3 4
  * curve_x        (curve_x) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
  * curve_y        (curve_y) int64 0 1
Data variables:
    DateTime       (MeasurementID) datetime64[ns] 1970-01-01 ... 1970-01-01T00:00:00.040000
    PositionX      (MeasurementID) float64 0.7422 0.4789 0.7673 0.2552 0.8817
    Filter         (MeasurementID) <U5 'green' 'green' 'green' 'green' 'green'
    curve_voltage  (MeasurementID, curve_x, curve_y) int64 11 40 51 ... 38 26 64
    curve_current  (MeasurementID, curve_x) int64 88 24 57 32 75 ... 60 25 40 3

>>> ds['curve_voltage'].mean()  # global average over all voltage curves
<xarray.DataArray 'curve_voltage' ()>
array(49.26)

>>> ds['curve_voltage'].mean('curve_x')  # average only over curve_x dimension
ds['curve_voltage'].mean('curve_x')

<xarray.DataArray 'curve_voltage' (MeasurementID: 5, curve_y: 2)>
array([[47.06, 50.73],
       [53.1 , 45.41],
       [51.41, 50.33],
       [49.12, 46.26],
       [47.94, 51.24]])
Coordinates:
  * MeasurementID  (MeasurementID) int64 0 1 2 3 4
  * curve_y        (curve_y) int64 0 1
```

Of course, you can (and should) give your additional dimensions more meaningful names than `curve_x` and `curve_y`.